# open Whats app from iOS application and handle cancel click in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sharing, whatsapp

In my application having sharing text on whatsapp... and when cancel from whatsapp its back to original ios app .. 
i don't know how to handle cancel click of whatsapp in ios ..
please resolved my problem ..
 i used below code for sharing text...

```
NSString * msg = @"YOUR MSG";
NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];
NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlWhats stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
} else {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what sharing library you are using

Comment: have a look into this http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: as you said "In VLCC " app redirect to app when cancel the sharing, in  here sharing time on whatsapp shows two option 1. send 2. cancel , if I select the cancel in whatsapp -- it does not redirect to app, VLCC also not did this concept ,

Comment: I worked on 2 projects using whatsapp sharing, your shared content for example YOUR MSG+URL --> it rethrow to ur app using deep linking concept , else with out share the content we can't access it , it is out of control in your app

Comment: @RahulMishra -- can you give example for this scenario , don't give this link http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: then how to working in VLCC application?

Comment: @Stela - as per your reply i tried in VLCC also not did this , when sharing is over in whatsapp, if you select your text is redirect to your app this we can do , this is possible , with out sharing how can we do this , for example purpose if you share in Facebook --> if you cancel the login button the Facebook is stay in safari , it does not rethrow your app, you can manually redirect to your app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89363/discussion-between-stela-and-anbu-karthik).